# How to create a factory?

Tags: c#, types, dictionary, factory

At this momment, I'm dealing with a mapper class which should be work as a factory.

Until now, I'm using a dictionary as the mapper.

```
IDictionary<string, Type> mapper;
```

The idea is when I get one value of the dictionary, this should be instanced, for example:

```
var foo = mapper["foo"];  // this should return the instance of foo
```

And another problem is:

```
var foo2 = mapper["foo"]  // should be the same instance of foo (foo == foo2)
```

Months ago, I guess had watched something about containers, I'm not sure if the term is correct and if this can help me.
Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I don't really have any code. What I was thinking is the dictionary should have as value a Func<> instead of Type, or use the class Activator as the intermediate, although I guess these are not good options. I plan to add more than 100 items in code behind, and it'll be so tired.

Comment: Please be a bit more prceise, what's the code that creates the object? I'm sure I've developed something simmilar but need more info.

Comment: The containers you were talking about is referring to the Dependency Injection container. There are several available libraries that do what you want to do, unless you have your own reason to create your own solution for this?

Comment: Well, this something like a factory dictionary, do you think that those container can behave like a creational factory?

Comment: I would be best to avoid inventing your own terminology.  "Creational mapper" doesn't mean anything.  Any factory creates.  Chuck those words, describe what you want to *do*.

Comment: Have a look at Dependency Injection Containers... these can be used to dynamically generate objects.  I've used Unity pretty heavily, but any of them accomplish the same goal... http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
abstract class MyBase { }
class Type1 : MyBase { }
class Type2 : MyBase { }
class Type3 : MyBase { }

private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<MyBase>> sConstructors =
   new Dictionary<Type, Func<MyBase>>
{
   { typeof(Type1), () => new Type1() },
   { typeof(Type2), () => new Type2() },
   { typeof(Type3), () => new Type3() }   
};

...

Type type = typeof(Type1);
MyBase myBase = sConstructors[type]();
```

Using reflection you can even build these automatically instead of having to maintain them manually.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the [Service Locator Anti-Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

Instead look into what @drumboog suggested - [Dependency Injection Containers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx).

A full explanation of this literally requires a [book](http://manning.com/seemann/).